# How to read properties of object stored in a class library

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and keep running into this problem:

I created a windows app with visual studios 2015 and added a class library to it to store the classes. the library is linked to the app in references and the using:namespace command at the top of the screen is written, but i cant seem to use the stored data of the objects in the classes.

the class

```
public class Area
{
    //field -> properties of the object
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaTitle { get; set; }
    public string AreaDescription { get; set; }


    // constructor -> creates objects
    public Area (int id, string title, string description)
    {
        this.AreaID = id;
        this.AreaTitle = title;
        this.AreaDescription = description;
    }

    //method that uses constructor to create ('instantiate') objects
    public static void CreateArea()
    {
        Area home = new Area(1, "Home", "This is your home");
        Area area2 = new Area(2, "Field", "Youre at a field");
        Area area3 = new Area(3, "Mine", "Youre in a mine");
        Area area4 = new Area(4, "Market", "Youre at a market");
    }
}
```

the ui code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Area.CreateArea(); //to make shure the 4 objects exist
    }
    // just to test if button works, and when program stops working 
    public int counter = 1;

    public void btnImput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTitle.Text = $"counter is {counter}";
        counter++;

    }

    public void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportAreaDiscription(home); //doesnt recognise home
        lblTitle.Text = home.AreaDescripting;  //doesnt work either

    }

    //im trying a method cosue just typing the text didnt work either
    public void ReportAreaDiscription(Area areadiscription)
    {
        lblDescription.Text = $"{areadiscription.AreaDescription}";
    }
}
```

/* ok so here is the question. wy wont the program recognise home.AreaDescription at line 30?
 * error message is -> the name 'home' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Because "home" is a variable which isn't declared nor instantiated. I expect you want to create a variable of type Area inside your form. You're just calling a static method on Area. That's all.

Comment: home is being used as a local variable in the scope of the `CreateArea` and does not have scope outside of it. You need to declare `home` inside the scope of `btnCreate_Click` in order for that to work. Also you have `home.AreaDescripting` which is mispelled

Comment: `CreateArea` shouldn't be a member of class `Area`. If you need instances of `Area` , then the variables referencing them should be in the correct scope. Where, when and who instanciates them depends ...

Comment: new user, be kind at least the question is quite well formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new in programmation, in order to search a simple solution for your problem, you should look at acces modifiers in c#.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers
```

To explain your case, your variables

```
    Area home = new Area(1, "Home", "This is your home");
    Area area2 = new Area(2, "Field", "Youre at a field");
    Area area3 = new Area(3, "Mine", "Youre in a mine");
    Area area4 = new Area(4, "Market", "Youre at a market");
```

are visible only in your CreateArea method.

In order to reach a variable or a property from another class or another application who references your library, you should declare public properties like your

```
public int AreaID { get; set; }
public string AreaTitle { get; set; }
public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
```

variables.

In order to reach a variable or property of a class of a library from an application who references the library, you should use public acces modifier.
Depending your goal, you should use internal, protected or private access modifiers.

And if you look at the link on the top of the response, you sould find detailled informations.

Comment: Those are not "global variables"! They are public properties which is not at all the same thing!

Comment: I changed my response. You are right.